# Logics with infinitely long expressions

Tags: logic

Infinitary logics allow expressions formed for possibly infinite length restricted by two respective cardinals $\kappa,\lambda$ corresponding to the first-order language. My question is if there are any concrete results on sole propositional logics allowing infinite expressions(without quantifiers and a universe of discourse)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an extensive literature on infinitary propositional logic.

A good starting point is chapters 4-5 of the book [Languages with Expressions of Infinite Length](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/journal/0049237X/36/supp/C?sdc=1), which talk about infinitary propositional logic in detail.

If you're interested in *nonclassical* (e.g. intuitionistic) infinitary propositional logics, then the following articles may interest you:

- **Intuitionistic/Many valued**: [Infinitary propositional intuitionistic logic](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1093883041) by Kalicki, and [A new higherarchy of infinitary propositional logics](http://www.latd2016.co.za/LavickaNogueraLATD2016Abstract.pdf) by Lavicka and Noguera.
- **Modal**: [Infinitary modal logic and generalized Kripke semantics](http://www.fupress.net/index.php/adf/article/viewFile/11278/10791) by Minari, and [A model existence theorem in infinitary propositional modal logic](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30226525?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by Segerberg.

Comment: Incidentally, I found all these sources on the first page of results after googling "infinitary propositional logic."

Comment: Isn't Woodin's extender algebra uses---to some extent---something similar to obtain every real is generic over an iterated ultrapower of some fixed countable model?

Comment: @AsafKaragila No idea - I don't know that result. (It sounds cool, though - citation?)

Comment: Oh, I don't know about citation. It's a Woodin result. So maybe unpublished? ;)

Comment: @AsafKaragila [Aaaaaaarrrrrgh ....](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJfowXTXOfU)

Comment: Well, truth be told, this is probably published in one place or another. I'm just too lazy to look for it. But I'm guessing that "Woodin Extender algebra forcing" would be a good start for finding this result.